# How to fix Laravel "Post method is not supported for this route"?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth

I am trying to create authentication using Laravel Passport, I have configured everything the right way as mentioned in the official documentation. The GET Route method works perfectly (see the code below), but when I try the POST Route method I always get this error:

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

P.S: I am using Postman for the test.

I have tried to include CSRF token but nothing happens, and I get the same error.

**Controller**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response(['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 422);
        }

        $request['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);
        $user = User::create($request->toArray());
        $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
        $response = ['token' => $token];

        return response($response, 200);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if ($user) {
            if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
                $response = ['token' => $token];

                return response($response, 200);
            } else {
                $response = "Password missmatch";

                return response($response, 422);
            }

        } else {
            $response = 'User does not exist';

            return response($response, 422);
        }
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->user()->token();
        $token->revoke();
        $response = 'You have been succesfully logged out!';

        return response($response, 200);
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/login', 'Api\AuthController@login')->name('login.api');
Route::post('/register', 'Api\AuthController@register')->name('register.api');
```

I expect to get user registered, and it returns the auth token, but it shows me 
"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Comment: "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods : GET, HEAD" -- which route did you hit of the three?

Comment: The first route should be in `api.php`, right? So the url should be with a prefix `api/user`. I think you haven't included all information in your question.

Comment: @senty yes I had to make the routes in api.php ... It works perfectly now thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should be in `api.php`

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old post, but found it when I was searching for a similar problem so adding my solution here.
I spent hours working on a similar problem with testing password resets with Fortify in Laravel. In the end, I found that the problem was with the headers in Postman.  I had to add a header: `Accept application/json` The default header for Accept was `*/*`

Comment: The original question was answered in the comments and it was about routing. If you've had a "similar problem" please describe it, because it could be a different problem not related with routing. I think yours was related to the response type you were receiving.

Comment: I had such problem with "The POST method is not supported for this route" when there was an error response. Yet all my routes was working fine
So it solved my problem, you rock!